# Recursive printing function deletes elements of parameter

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures

I created a function which goes through any `dict`/`list` hybrid data structure, and prints it, using recursion (because it's more efficient and fun). The problem is that once called, it destroys its parameter variable. 
And not only the parameter variable, but any other father/son substructure:

```
Father variable: Son = Father
Son variable: InheritSonSecondLevel = Son
```

If I call my function as `Func(Son)` or `Func(Father)` or `Func(InheritSonSecondLevel)`, all the structure content will be destroyed. There is not much I can try. 
I'm using this hybrid data structure. 
Let's call it: hybrid.

This is inside a `for`.
`hybrid = functionX()`

As `printRecursiveDictionary()` will kill my content, I call it at the end. 
And create a `list` based on hybrid's content. Something like: 
`fullContent=fullContent+[["A Label",hybrid]]`

Then `printRecursiveDictionary()` is called. The `for` ends, and I use `fullContent()` for something. Then, surprise, there is just a matrix with labels and empty dictionaries left.

```
def printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary,deepness=0):
if(isinstance(dictionary,list) and dictionary!=[]):
    if(isinstance(dictionary[0],dict) or 
    isinstance(dictionary[0],list)):
        print("A")
        printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary[0],deepness+1)
else:
    print("B")
    print("\t"*deepness,dictionary[0])
    printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary[1:],deepness)

elif(isinstance(dictionary,dict) and dictionary!={}):
    if(isinstance(list(dictionary.values())[0],dict) or 
    isinstance(list(dictionary.values())[0],list)):
        print("C")
        print("\t"*deepness+str(list(dictionary.keys())[0]))
        printRecursiveDictionary(
        list(dictionary.values())[0],
        deepness+1
        )
    else:
        print("D")
        print("\t"*deepness+str(list(dictionary.keys())[0])+":"+str(list(dictionary.values())[0]))
        dictionary.pop(list(dictionary.keys())[0])
        printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary,deepness)


x=[0,{1:1,2:2,3:3}]
print(x)
y = x
print(y)
printRecursiveDictionary(y)

print(y)
print(x)
```

The result will be:

```
[0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
[0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
B
 0
A
D
    1:1
D
    2:2
D
    3:3
[0, {}]
[0, {}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that once it is called, it destroys the parameter
>   variable.

Below is a rework of `printRecursiveDictionary()` that doesn't destroy its parameter.  This code assumes Python 3, if you need Python 2, leave a comment and I'll provide a modification for the older version:

```
def printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary, deepness=0):
    if isinstance(dictionary, list) and dictionary:
        if isinstance(dictionary[0], (dict, list)):
            print("A")
            printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary[0], deepness + 1)
        else:
            print("B")
            print("\t" * deepness, dictionary[0])
            printRecursiveDictionary(dictionary[1:], deepness)

    elif isinstance(dictionary, dict) and dictionary:

        (key, value), *remainder = dictionary.items()

        if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            print("C")
            print("\t" * deepness, key)
            printRecursiveDictionary(value, deepness + 1)
        else:
            print("D")
            print("\t" * deepness, str(key) + ":" + str(value))
            printRecursiveDictionary(dict(remainder), deepness)

x = [0, {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}]
y = x
print('x:', x)
print('y:', y)

printRecursiveDictionary(y)
print('x:', x)
print('y:', y)
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
x: [0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
y: [0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
B
 0
A
D
     1:1
D
     2:2
D
     3:3
x: [0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
y: [0, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
>
```

Comment: I see. 
It has sense, the problem was the pop as a way to display the value instead of just taking the key,value. 
Thanks cdlane!